# Given a set $A$, how do I prove that there exists a set of all sets $x$ such that $\bigcup x=A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am working with Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms. Specifically, I am allowed to assume the Axiom of Pair, Axiom Schema of Comprehension, Axiom of Union, and Axiom of Power Set, etc. (not yet allowed to use Axiom of Choice but that really should not be relevant to this question)

I'm given that there's a set $A$.

I know that by the Axiom of Union, the following collection is a set:

$$\bigcup A = \left\{x \mid \exists\, y \in A \text{ such that } x \in y\right\}$$

I also know how to prove that any set is a subset of the power set of the union of itself. For $A$, this would be $$A \subseteq \mathcal{P}\left(\bigcup A\right)$$

I need to show that the set of all sets whose unions are $A$ exists. This set should be a subset of the power set of $A$ but I'm not sure how to actually prove that it exists.

I want to contruct the power set of $A$ and use the Axiom Schema of Comprehension to show that this set $B$ exists, with

$$B = \left\{x \mid \bigcup x = A\right\}$$

Any help would be appreciated ... again, I feel like this is going to be a one-liner :/

Comment: Are you using $\mathcal U$ instead of $\cup$?

Comment: @Ian Is $B$ a subset of $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}A$? I thought it was just a subset of $\mathcal{P}A$. Anyway, how exactly do I show that $B$ can be written as a subset of $\mathcal{P}A$, or an element of $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}A$? This is my problem ...

Comment: @GitGud I'm using $\mathcal{U}$ as [this thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Arbitrary_unions). I think Brian M. Scott fixed my notation (thanks for that).

Comment: My eyes nearly got cancer from that notation $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @Vincent: `\bigcup` gives you $\bigcup$, and `\cup` gives you $\cup$. Similarly with `\bigcap` and `\cap` for intersection symbols.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a set $B$ that you can define from $A$ that is big enough so that if $\bigcup x=A$, then $x\in B$. Suppose that $\bigcup x\subseteq A$. If $y\in x$, then every element of $y$ is an element of $A$, so $y\subseteq A$, and $y\in\wp(A)$. This means that $x\subseteq\wp(A)$, and therefore $x\in\wp(\wp(A))$. Thus, you can take $B=\wp(\wp(A))$: it contains as an element every $x$ that could possibly satisfy $\bigcup x=A$.

Comment: I can't vote you up for some reason, but thanks a lot!

EDIT: Just figured out the checkmark

Comment: @VincentLuo If you're registered, you should be able to up vote. If you're registered and you can't up vote, flag this answer for moderator attention and explain what's happening.

Comment: @GitGud Not true, need 15 reputation (what it says when I try to upvote)

Comment: @VincentLuo I was unaware, thanks.

Comment: @GitGud: I’ve always thought that it would make sense to let even a first-timer vote on answers to his or her own question, but the $15$ rep limit is across the board.

Comment: @Vincent: Just so you know, you now have the rep to vote up any question or answer (but are under absolutely no obligation to do so); I just didn’t get round to upvoting your question until I’d finished answering another.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott +1, thanks ... this site is better than quora for sure